# Mongrel does not shut down using CTRL-C

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, mongrel, copy-paste, macos

I am building a Rails 2.3.5 application using Ruby 1.8.7. My development platform is a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard 10.6.4. Often during development I can not shut down mongrel using the Ctrl-C command in Terminal. It does work sometimes but 8 times out of 10 it does not work. I do not think the Ctrl-C failure is linked to any particular action that I previously performed in my Rails application. Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also have a MacBook Pro running the same version of Snow Leopard and have not seen this issue.  Perhaps it's an issue with your shell?  Though I can't imagine why that would be the case.  Are you sure there isn't some problem with your control key (can you test it in another application)?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem, can's stop Mongrel with Cntr-C. With 1.8.7 all works well, but with 1.9.2 it just hangs and never terminates.

Mac 10.5.8
Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Actually I fixed this issue, I started using Thin server instead of Mongrel, and it works well :)